# Need relationship data in Laravel

Tags: mysql, laravel

All laravel guys, please if you can help me out. I have DB as PostgreSQL. I have four table as below:

Food: Id, Name

Benefit: Id, Name

Benefit_rating: id, name

Food_benefit: Id, food_id,Benefit_id,Benefit_rating_id

I need one query when id of food is known and it fetches food name (Food.name) from Food and list all food benefit (benefit_rating.name) and its rating (Benefit_rating.name).

Now, understand that Food_benefit holds relationship of food, benefit and benefit rating releavant to food.

I can not have many to many relationship as pivot table is designed that way [Cant alter design].

Any raw query sort of stuff suggestion?

Comment: You can still have many to many. You can have `Food::belongsToMany(Benefit)`, `Benefit::belongsToMany(Food)`, `Benefit::belongsToMany(BenefitRating)`, `BenefitRating::belongsToMany(Benefit)` and lastly `Food::belongsToMany(BenefitRating)`, `BenefitRating::belongsToMany(Food)`. Then you could do something like this: `Food::with('benefits.benefitRatings')->find($id)`.

Answer (score 0):

I assume you're using Eloquent and already defined relationships between the models.

You can use [nested eager loading](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/eloquent-relationships#lazy-eager-loading):

```
$food = Food::where('id', $foodId)
            ->with('foodBenefits.benefitRating', 'foodBenefits.benefit')
            ->first();
```

Or [eager loading](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/eloquent-relationships#eager-loading):

```
$food = Food::find($foodId);
$foodBenefit = FoodBenefit::where('food_id', $foodId)
                          ->with('benefit', 'benefitRating')
                          ->get();
```

Comment: Kudos! Bang on.